# How to generate distribution graphs like the example below in R

Tags: r, plot, graph

I have tried to replicate the graph of the example in R but I have not been able to reach a similar result.

I would appreciate the help.

[image]

Comment: https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~luke/classes/STAT4580/histdens.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question and include the code you have tried, a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the density functions of the distributions you want to plot, if they're inbuilt, such as `dnorm()`, `dt()`, `dbeta()` etc.

Then you can use the `ggplot2` package to plot the densities. An example:

```
library(ggplot2)

x = seq(-5, 5, length.out = 2000)

ndens <- dnorm(x)
tdens <- dt(x, df = 5)

df <- data.frame(norm=ndens, t=tdens)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_density(aes(y=t), fill="red", alpha=0.1, stat="identity") +
  geom_density(aes(y=norm), fill="blue", alpha=0.1, stat="identity")
```

[image]

Here, the red curve represents the t distribution with 5 degrees of freedom, while the blue curve represents the standard normal distribution.